# Setting Layer Properties Using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, layers, symbology

I am writing an ArcPy script that creates a Point Density Raster file, and then changes the following properties in the resulting layer:

1. Symbology

   Classified

   Classes = 10

   Classification Method = Geometrical Interval

   Excluded Value = 0
2. Display

   Resample during display using:  bilinear interpolation

I know I can set `lyr.symbology.numClasses = 10`. and `lyr.symbology.excludedValues = 0`, and even create a dummy layer with the above properties (symbologyLayer) and `arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, symbologyLayer)`.  Is there a way to do this simply by setting attributes of `lyr.symbology`, do I have to do it in one fell swoop with `ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management`, or is there a better way?

Comment: I would agree with Jason I usually do all the symbology stuff in one fell swoop with ApplySymbologyFromLayer and include the "Dummy Layer(s)" in my tool package, you can also use Resample_management to resample rasters.

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing a geoprocessing script, I'd recommend authoring a .lyr file you bundle with your toolbox and [set the symbology in the script tool parameters to point to the .lyr file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Setting_script_tool_parameters/00150000000n000000/) (see the "Symbology" part of the dialog).